# Ruby style, how to write this if statement

Tags: ruby

```
puts 'hello' if some_id.nil? or (u.some_id == some_id)
```

Is this clear and the only way to write this logic in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative, although not necessarily any better:

```
puts 'hello' if [nil, u.some_id].contains? some_id
```

Comment: I don't disagree, but mine would be more readable if you had another "or" clause that needed to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether there's an oror equivalent to the andand gem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make it significantly more readable. You probably can decrease number of character, but it won't make it easier to read.

Another alternative would be eliminating `nil` at all:

```
some_id = get_the_some_id or u.some_id #default to u.some_id

# some time later
puts 'hello' if u.some_id == some_id
```